# Crystal report development install error. mapwinGis failed. visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Crystal report development install error. mapwinGis failed. visual studio 2012

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI7wG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Install **MICROSOFT VISUAL C++ 2005 or later RUNTIME LIBRARIES (X86)**, before installing crystal report.